# How can I change neo4j Id to UUID and get finder methods to work?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

Neo4j needs an id field to work which is of type Long. This works well with Spring data neo4j. I would like to have another field of type UUID and have T findOne(T id) to work with my UUID not neo generated Ids.

As I am using Spring Data Rest, I don't want to expose neo's id in the URL.

http://localhost:8080/resource/{neoId}

to

http://localhost:8080/resource/{uuid}

Any ideas if this is possible?

UPDATED

```
{
    name: "Root",
    resourceId: "00671e1a-4053-4a68-9c59-f870915e3257",
    _links: {
    self: {
        href: "http://localhost:8080/resource/9750"
    },
    parents: {
         href: "http://localhost:8080/resource/9750/parents"
    },
    children: {
        href: "http://localhost:8080/resource/9750/children"
              }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to the finder method in your repository you are at liberty to either override the one provided in the `CrudRepository` in your own interface, or provide an alternative which may be `T findByUuid(Long uuid)`.

Depending on how you are modelling your classes you can rely on the derived query from your method name, or you can annotate with a query, something like:

```
@Query(value = "MATCH (n:YourNodeType{uuid:{0}) RETURN n")
```

If you are going to be using a specific UUID class then you will need to tell Neo how to persist the UUID value. If you are will store it as a String (as seems sensible) then I believe there is no need to annotate the field, anything else then you will need a `GraphProperty` annotation:

```
@GraphProperty(propertyType = Long.class)
```

Again depending on the class of UUID you may need to register a conversion class with Spring which implements the `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` interface and converts between your domain class type (UUID) and the stored type (String).

Or, just convert the UUID to a string and store it yourself and don't worry about all the conversion.

Whatever you do, make sure that your new `uuid` is indexed and presumably unique.

Comment: Thanks John, I got the finder method to work http://localhost:8080/resource/00671e1a-4053-4a68-9c59-f870915e3257 which is what I wanted. However, the link to self, parent and children still have node id see the updated question. This is obvious but is there a way to change this to UUID as well

Answer (score 0):

You can add a *String* attribute to your entities, calling it *uuid*, and simply declare a *E findByUuid(String uuid)* in your *Repository* for *E*, Spring Data will automatically generate code for it.
For example:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Entity {
    ...
    @Indexed
    private String uuid;
    ...
    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }
    void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
    ...
}

public interface EntityRepository extends GraphRepository<Entity> {
    ...
    Entity findByUuid(String uuid);
    ...
}
```