# How can you customise self, parent, children links in spring data rest with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

I am using spring data rest to create an API over neo4j. I don't want to expose nodeId in my URLs, therefore I have a UUID instead. More info on here:

[How can I change neo4j Id to UUID and get finder methods to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049110/how-can-i-change-neo4j-id-to-uuid-and-get-finder-methods-to-work)

How can I modify the auto-generated links by the spring-data-rest to reflect the change to UUID instead of nodeId?

Thanks

----UPDATED---

```
public class CustomBackendIdConverter implements BackendIdConverter {

@Autowired
PracticeAreaRepository practiceAreaRepository;

@Override
public Serializable fromRequestId(String id, Class<?> entityType) {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String toRequestId(Serializable id, Class<?> entityType) {
    if(entityType.equals(PracticeArea.class)) {
        PracticeArea c = (PracticeArea) id;
        return c.getPracticeAreaId().toString();
    }
    return id.toString();
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> delimiter) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data REST has a `BackendIdConverter` SPI interface for you implement to translate what's discovered as the identifying part of the URI into whatever you're using in the repository's `findOne(…)` method.

Simply create an implementation of this interface that does the two-way conversion and register it as Spring bean in your ApplicationContext and it will be picked up by Spring Data REST automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to do what you suggested and using this as a baseline, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801575/customizing-hateoas-link-generation-for-entities-with-composite-ids. Throwing errors at              PracticeArea c = (PracticeArea) id;
Do I need to create other two classes as suggested in that answer, I guess not?