# Spring Data Neo4j + Spring Data Rest: Using a Natural Key for all CRUD operations instead of the Neo4J node Id

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

I'm writing writing a Spring Restful microservice that relies on Spring Data Rest and Spring Data Neo4J.

We don't want to expose the internal Neo4J node identifier  in the HAL links of the JSON response. The reason being (as far as I understand) that these identifiers are reused by Neo4J in case of node deletion. If this is the case this will present us with data integrity problems. And so we'd rather use a natural key, for example, UUID. **Please correct me if my assumption regarding the reuse of neo4J node Ids is wrong**.

What we want to achieve is using a Natural Key for all CRUD operations instead of the node Id (ie: PUT http://localhost:8080/apiname/5448ae86-fe87-4daf-bfb5-985522a1cf14 with some body).

Our first approach was to extend *NodeGraphRepositoryImp* . E.g.

```
protected Node getById(UUID id) {
    Node node = (Node) this.findByPropertyValue("uuid_id", id);
    return template.getNode(node.getId());
}
```

And instantiate it by injecting a customized *Neo4jTemplate* in the Neo4J configuration.

However this approach doesn't work for the following reasons:

1) I cannot define any other *idProperty* different from the one annotated with *@GraphId* in the *NodeEntity* class. As a result Spring Data Rest ends up trying to assign the natural key (e.g. UUID)  to the neo4j node id field (that is a Long) and fails on type conversion.

2) It seems that the Spring Data Neo4J is not using our custom class that extends NodeGraphRepositoryImpl but the original not extended NodeGraphRepositoryImpl class instead.

Maybe this approach is wrong. Could you please recommend a way to achieve it?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Rest introduced a **BackendIdConverter** for overriding/customizing the field that gets exposed in the URIs.

Please have a look at [DATAREST-155](https://jira.spring.io/plugins/servlet/mobile%23issue/DATAREST-155) (https://jira.spring.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/DATAREST-155)

Can you give it a try?

You can also have a look at the following thread:

[How can you customise self, parent, children links in spring data rest with neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190253/how-can-you-customise-self-parent-children-links-in-spring-data-rest-with-neo4)

Comment: Hi @theeagermichael, thanks a lot for your reply.

I don't see how the **BackendIdConverter** SPI interface can help me, as it customizes _how_ the entity ids are exposed but  it doesn't allow customizing _what_ field is exposed as entity id in the rest interface (currently it uses the Neo4j internal id (@GraphId field) if you are using the Spring Data Neo4j library.

In fact, the **BackendIdConverter** methods only receive the id property value and the  entity Type information of the Id.

Any ideas?

Thanks again

Comment: Mhm, I see. You could do something like `return neo4jTemplate.getNode((Long) id).getProperty("uuid").toString();` within `toRequestId` but that would add an otherwise unnecessary additional lookup of the node just to get the other attribute.