# Serialize Value Object to String in Spring Data REST

Tags: json, jackson, spring-data-rest

currently I'm designing a domain model for an application. I created a simple value object that's basically just a wrapper around a string enhanced with some business logic.

Now the default behaviour of jackson is to render the object like

```
"routerId": {
    "routerId": "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
}
```

for

```
@Embeddable
data class RouterId(val routerId: String) {

    init {
        val octets = routerId.split(":")

        if (octets.size != 6) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("$routerId does not consist of 6 octets")
        }

        for (octet in octets) {
            Integer.parseInt(octet, 16)
        }
    }
}
```

I stumbeld accross http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.6.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#_adding_custom_de_serializers_to_jackson_s_objectmapper and tried to supply my custom jackson module to handle serialization with

```
class NicemediaModule : SimpleModule("NicemediaModule") {

    override fun setupModule(context: SetupContext?) {
        val serializers = SimpleSerializers()
        serializers.addSerializer(RouterId::class.java, RouterIdSerializer())

        context?.addSerializers(serializers)
    }
}

private class RouterIdSerializer : StdSerializer<RouterId>(RouterId::class.java) {

    override fun serialize(value: RouterId?, gen: JsonGenerator?, provider: SerializerProvider?) {
        gen?.writeString(value?.routerId)
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
open class SpringDataRestConfiguration : RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configureJacksonObjectMapper(objectMapper: ObjectMapper?) {
        objectMapper?.registerModule(NicemediaModule())
    }
}
```

but this only leads to

```
"routerId": {
    "content": "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
}
```

Could anyone point out what I would have to do to serialize the `RouterId` just to a plain  string like `"routerId": "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"`?

Edit:
I added `@Component` to my `SimpleModule` so that Spring Boot loads it by default and wrote a litte test to see if the `ObjectMapper` works.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
class JsonSerializationTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper

    @Test
    fun serializeRouterId() {
        val routerId: String = "11:11:11:11:11:11"
        assertEquals("\"$routerId\"", mapper.writeValueAsString(RouterId(routerId)))
    }
}
```

works quite fine. This may be an indicator that my code is working the whole time but Spring Data REST fails to serialize my model at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing a custom `BackendIdConverter` SPI as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190253/how-can-you-customise-self-parent-children-links-in-spring-data-rest-with-neo4) answer.  Works like a charm!